# OWL Carousel - embeded twitter tweets - mess on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

On my page I have slider (showing my twitter tweets) based on OWL Carousel and on desktop looks nice.

[image: On Desktop looks nice and slide nice]

But on mobile view there is a mess.

[image: View on mobile]

One overlaps the other, etc.
How to modify css to resolve this issue for mobile view?

here is my code:

**

### HTML

```
    <div class="card-twitter">
    <div class="img-twitter">
            
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr"></blockquote> </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="card-twitter">
    <div class="img-twitter">
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr"></blockquote> </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="card-twitter">
    <div class="img-twitter">
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr"></blockquote> </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
    max-width: 1100px;
    display: flex;
    }
    .slider-twitter .card-twitter{
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 10px;
    }
    .slider-twitter .card-twitter .img-twitter{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .slider-twitter .card-twitter .img-twitter img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    }
    .slider-twitter .card-twitter .content{
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    .card-twitter .content .title{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    }
    .card-twitter .content .sub-title{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #e74c3c;
    line-height: 20px;
    }
    .card-twitter .content p{
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 10px 0;
    }
    .card-twitter .content .btn{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px 0;
    }
    .card-twitter .content .btn button{
    background: #e74c3c;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
    }
    .card-twitter .content .btn button:hover{
    transform: scale(0.9);
    }
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css